# Install4j removes response file variables when updating

Tags: install4j

when i'm updating my application, install4j removes a couple of response file variables from the response.varfile.

The missing variables are all of the type Long. I can see in the log file, that these variables are set, but are somehow removed when the update is finished.

The variables are bound to a textfield in the installer, but not in the updater, could this be the problem? I have checked "register variables for response file" though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This only occurs in install4j 5 and earlier.

Only variables that are **registered as response file variables** are written to the response file. Variables that are bound to form components are automatically registered as response file variables. This only happens when the form component is actually shown, so in the case of an updater installer with a fast installation path, that may not be the case.

Variables definitions that are read from a response file are not registered as response files variables in install4j 5 and earlier. In install4j 6 those variables are registered automatically unless the corresponding setting is changed on the "Load a response file" action.

As a workaround for install4j 5 and earlier, you can programmatically register response file variables like this:

```
context.registerResponseFileVariable("variableName");
```

for example in a "Run script" action in the "Startup" node of the installer.

Comment: Hello Ingo, thanks for your (fast) reply. The variables are registered as response file variable. I've tested the `context.registerReponseFileVariable` script and it worked, the variables are now in the response file, I'm using version 6 of install4j though.

Comment: Another point is why are other variables not deleted, which are also bound to textfields and not shown in the updated?

Comment: The updater application is not relevant in this respect, only the downloaded installer that is executed by the updater. You can check the log file in ".install4j/installation.log" to see details about variable assignments and "Load a response file" actions.

Comment: Sorry with updater i meant the installer, im not using the downloader (yet).